# CasperJS test unnamed input element value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, casperjs

I have the following input tag for AngularJS:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.firstName" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName">
```

And I'm using the following CasperJS code to test the value:

```
test.assertField('firstName', 'A Dummy Name');
```

For AngularJS the name field is not required and I do not wish to use this. For CasperJS however, it is.

Can I use my CasperJS test to use the id or ng-model attribute to get the value of the field to compare? As far as I found out I can't, because value is not an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use:

```
test.assertField({type: 'css', path: '#firstName'}, 'First Name ID exists', 'First Name ID does not exist');
```

or

```
test.assertFieldCSS('#firstName', 'First Name ID exists', 'First Name ID does not exist');
```